# ASP.Net Model binding - WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, model-binding

I have been asked to work on an ASP.Net WebForms project and I want to use ModelBinding like I do in ASP.Net MVC.

I am having some problems in getting this to work and would like some help if possible.

If I want to bind a model to objects on a Form I need to do this in a FormView, GridView and so on but in this instance I want to use a FormView.

The below code is a simplified version of what I am working with but everybit relevant.

```
<asp:FormView runat="server" ID="frmMain" ItemType="WebFormsModelBinding.TestModel" SelectMethod="TestBinding_select" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName" Text="<%#: BindItem.Name %>" />
        <br/>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtAge" Text=" <%#: BindItem.Age %>" />

    </ItemTemplate>

</asp:FormView>
<asp:Button runat="server" id="bttnInsert" Text="button"/>
```

I have a JQuery script that is attempting to pass the data back to the model but I keep getting a Internal 500 Error

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("#MainContent_bttnInsert")
            .click(function() {


                var params = {
                    Name: "Dave",
                    Age: 55
                }

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "default.aspx/TestBinding",
                    data: JSON.stringify(params),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    //success: function (data) {
                    success: function () {
                        alert("it worked");
                        return false;

                    },
                    error: function (data) {

                        console.log(data); 
                        alert("didnt work");
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
    })
```

This should hit this code in the default page

```
    public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static bool TestBinding(TestModel model)
    {

        return true;
    }

    public TestModel TestBinding_select()
    {
        var model = new TestModel
        {
            Name = "Simon",
            Age = 33
        };

        return model;
    }
}

public class TestModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

}
```

The problems I am having is that as I cant use an ActionResult I have to declare a different object type as the return type. For this example I have chosen a bool and there is no specific reason for this.

In order to hit a WebMethod I have to make the method static.

The error that I am getting is

> "Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'model'."

So, I can pass a model to the UI and present it in the FormView in this instance, but I cannot pass a model back via JQuery or a postback.

Is there anything that I am missing, or do I really have to pass each variable back and then pass the values to the class thus making model binding almost pointless in WebForms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ware going to work with `WebForms`, you should get used to working with the `PostBack` model, or you're going to be constanty fighting against the selected framework.

But for the question at hand, try the following:

```
data: JSON.stringify({'model':params})
```

Comment: I am just trying this now, but what I have seen in terms of postbacks I haven't seen anything that would act in the manner of how I am trying to achieve this but have seen that I'd need to do it by looking at `Request.Form.... ` on each element which would be the same as having pass each variable via jquery

Comment: @SimonPrice Regarding the combination of webforms and modelbinding, I highly recommend the three part tutorial by ScottGu. First part available [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/web-forms-model-binding-part-1-selecting-data-asp-net-vnext-series).

Comment: Thanks, I've upvoted the comment too in case that will give you points too.  You've been a massive help thanks

Comment: Thanks, and good luck with your dive into the webforms world! :-)